# recommended correct picture size for background web

Tags: javascript, image, resolution, image-resizing, screen-resolution

I want to use various images in my background for a website. I've created a code which will open different images for different screen sizes. For now I only have 2 kind of images, this is the code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var randomImages = ['img1','img2','img3','img4','img5'];
var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImages.length);

 var $win = $(this);
 var isBig = $(window).width() > 1920 ? '_big' : '';
 var $img = $('#background').attr('src', '_img/bg/index_rnd/' + randomImages[rndNum] + isBig + '.jpg').css({'position':'fixed','top':0,'left':0});
    function resize() {
        if (($win.width() / $win.height()) < ($img.width() / $img.height())) {
          $img.css({'height':'100%','width':'auto'});
        } else {
          $img.css({'width':'100%','height':'auto'});
        }
    }
    $win.resize(function() { resize(); }).trigger('resize');
});
```

I will add more options for different sizes but before I go firther I would like to know what is a recommended size for the pictures. The quality of the picture is important but also the speed of the background. These are the sizes I have for the moment:

normal resolution up to 1920px wide, pictures with size **130KB-140KB**

pictures with more than 1920px wide, pictures with size **270KB-280KB**

I tried around the internet for similar cases but I cannot find anything. Could you let me know what are the averages or recomendations for this case?!?!

Thank you very much!

Dani

EDIT: MORE DETAILS////////////////

My original pictures are 4752 X 3168, .TIFF, resolution of 240px/inch and with a weight of 46MB. After I treat them in Photoshop, taking down their resolution, size and saving for web devices... I modify to the following:

resolution to 72px/inch
size 1426 X 950 
JPG 40 quality

I end up with a picture which is 162.1KB. This picture has to cover the whole screen once loaded so the sizes of the picture need to be close enough so it doesnt pixelate. Is this a good size or is there a better method with Photoshop to make smaller a big size picture and mantain its quality.

This will be for web users from Europe and South America. No data limit, most common resolution will be 1024x768 but I want the image to adapt to any other size with no pixelation.

Running out of possibilities so I would like some help here...

Thanks!!

Comment: There are no hard, fast rules here. You have to balance the trade-off between image quality and image size which is largely subjective.

Comment: +1 And remember that 64 Kb is more than anyone will ever need....

Answer (score 3):

This question is very hard to answer because it really depends on:

1. What kind of site it is.
2. If you have any kind of data limit.
3. The users: how fast their typical internet connection is, if they generally can wait longer for a sharper image, what their most common resolution is.

This is just a short list of things you might have to consider before making a **decision**.

Personally I think a 270KB - 280KB background image is way too much, especially for resolutions that is very uncommon. Not that many users out there with a resolution larger than 1920px wide.

Sorry for not being able to give you an direct and short answer, but maybe this helps a little bit atleast.

Comment: Hello SQVe, I just edited my question regarding your questions. Could you give me a hand with this one?!?! I hope that info helps

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero Personally I still find the image too large in size, but then again I'm a load-everything-really-really-fast freak. The size do seem quite fair for the resolution and if the quality is good. I'm unsure if the size of the image is good or not, I guess you have to test it and if it works it works... I would test playing around the the jpg quality settings, try to get it as low as possible but still have a decent quality. Also I would try it as png & gif, to see if that makes any size different. Good luck.